# How to hide series name in legend when the series is empty in Apache echarts?

Tags: legend, echarts, apache-echarts

I created a stacked line chart with echarts and I used the built-in transform to filter the provided data and ecSimpleTransform to aggregate the values. However, after filtering some datasets become empty, because none of their values match the filter condition. I would like to add a legend, but it also includes labels for the empty datasets. Is there a way to filter the legend values as well?

I attached a simplified version of the chart config.

I also created a [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/data-transform-simple-aggregate-forked-6x66t7?file=/index.js).

```
legendData= [...] //list of possible 'propertyOne' values
const chartConfig = {
      dataset: [
        {
          id: 'raw',
          dimensions: ['date', 'value', 'propertyOne', 'propertyTwo'],
          source: values,
        },
        {
          id: 'filtered',
          fromDatasetId: 'raw',
          transform: [
            {
              type: 'filter',
              config: {
                dimension: 'propertyTwo',
                '=': 'providedValue',
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        ...legendData.map(propertyOneValue=> {
          return {
            id: propertyOneValue,
            fromDatasetId: 'filtered',
            transform: [
              {
                type: 'filter',
                config: {
                  dimension: 'propertyOne',
                  '=': propertyOneValue,
                },
              },
              {
                type: 'ecSimpleTransform:aggregate',
                config: {
                  resultDimensions: [
                    { name: 'propertyOne', from: 'propertyOne' },
                    { name: 'sum', from: 'value', method: 'sum' },
                    { name: 'date', from: 'date' },
                  ],
                  groupBy: 'date',
                },
              },
            ],
          };
        }),
      ],
      tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis',
        confine: true,
      },
      yAxis: {
        nameLocation: 'middle',
        nameGap: 30,
        scale: true,
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        position: 'top',
      },
      grid: {
        bottom: 50,
        containLabel: true,
      },
      legend: {
        selected: { detail: false },
        data: legendData,
        bottom: 0,
        type: 'scroll',
      },
      series: [
        ...legendData.map(propertyOneValue => {
          return {
            name: propertyOneValue ,
            type: 'line' as 'line',
            areaStyle: {},
            datasetId: propertyOneValue,
            stack: 'Total',
            encode: {
              x: 'date',
              y: 'sum',
              itemName: 'propertyOne',
              tooltip: 'sum',
            },
          };
        }),
      ],
    }
```

Comment: can you add a sandbox?

Comment: Yes, I added a sandbox to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart's legend is going to display as many values as there are in `legend.data`. In your example, `legendData` still has 4 values when you assign it to `legend.data` instead of just being ["custom 1", "custom 2"].

One simple way of doing it would be to only add what you want in `legend.data` when you create it (instead of filtering legendData later).

```js
values.forEach((value) => {
  //just addind a second condition when pushing values to legendData
  if (!legendData.includes(value.propertyOne) && value.propertyTwo == "providedValue"){
    legendData.push(value.propertyOne);
  }
});
```

I don't know exactly what you intend to do with this application, but this solution works on the sandbox you provided.  Even later when you do `...legendData.map()`, you won't get poluted with useless values (from custom 3 & 4).